# Basis for the range and nullspace of the following $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space of polynomials of degree at most five with real co-efficient. Define the following Linear Map:

$T:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}\ $ where $T(p) = (p(1),\ p(2),\ p(3))$

That is the value of coordinates of $T(p)$ is values of $p$ at $1, 2, 3$.
(I think what the question is trying to say is that the value is $p$ evaluated at
$1, 2 ,3$)

i) find a basis for the null-space

ii) find a basis for the range space.

The above is a question I pulled from the net. Below is my attempt which I'm quite sure is wrong, hence any insight and help is deeply appreciated.

Attempt:

1.) Following the question, the null-space should contain all $p$ such that
    $p(1) = p(2) = p(3) = 0$
    Hence using this to form a linear system and explicitly solve it, I realize the first 3 co-efficient is a linear combination of the last 3. (It seem like I made a grave mistake in my previous proposed basis, hence I omitted it)

2.)Since the range is $\mathbb{R^3}$, I just use the standard basis.

Comment: $\{1,x^2,x^3\}$ can't be a basis for the nullspace, because none of those are in the nullspace. One element that is in the nullspace is $\{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\}$.

Comment: Notice that $T(1) = (1,1,1)$, $T(x^2) = (1,4,9)$ and $T(x^3) = (1,8,27)$, so none of the vectors in your purported basis of the null space actually belongs to the null space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use matrices for problems like this. Let
\begin{align*}
p_0(t) &= 1 &
p_1(t) &= t &
p_2(t) &= t^2 &
p_3(t) &= t^3 &
p_4(t) &= t^4 &
p_5(t) &= t^5 
\end{align*}
Note that $\alpha=\{p_0,\dotsc,p_5\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $\beta=\{\vec
e_1,\vec e_2,\vec e_3\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^3$.

Note that
\begin{array}{rcccrcrcrcrcrcrcrcrc}
T(p_0) & = & (1,1,1)    & = & 1\cdot\vec e_1 &+& 1 \cdot\vec e_2 &+& 1   \cdot\vec e_3 \\
T(p_1) & = & (1,2,3)    & = & 1\cdot\vec e_1 &+& 2 \cdot\vec e_2 &+& 3   \cdot\vec e_3 \\
T(p_2) & = & (1,4,9)    & = & 1\cdot\vec e_1 &+& 4 \cdot\vec e_2 &+& 9   \cdot\vec e_3 \\
T(p_3) & = & (1,8,27)   & = & 1\cdot\vec e_1 &+& 8 \cdot\vec e_2 &+& 27  \cdot\vec e_3 \\
T(p_4) & = & (1,16,81)  & = & 1\cdot\vec e_1 &+& 16\cdot\vec e_2 &+& 81  \cdot\vec e_3 \\
T(p_5) & = & (1,32,243) & = & 1\cdot\vec e_1 &+& 32\cdot\vec e_2 &+& 243 \cdot\vec e_3 
\end{array}
The matrix of $T$ relative to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is 
$$
[T]_\alpha^\beta=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 \\
1 & 3 & 9 & 27 & 81 & 243
\end{array}\right]
$$
Call this matrix $A$.

The null space of $T$ corresponds to the null space of $A$ and the range space
of $T$ corresponds to the column space of $A$. The advantage here is that
computing bases for these spaces can be done algorithmically.

To do so, note that 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 &   6 &  36 &  150 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -11 & -60 & -239 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &   6 &  25 &   90
\end{array}\right]
$$
This shows that the range of $T$ has dimension three and thus surjective. Hence
$\{\vec e_1,\vec e_2,\vec e_3\}$ is a basis for the range of $T$.

The rank-nullity theorem implies that the null space of $T$ has dimension $\dim
V-3=6-3=3$. The reduced row-echelon form above shows that the vectors
\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -6\\ 11\\ -6 \\ 1\\ 0\\ 0
  \end{bmatrix} &&
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -36\\ 60\\ -25\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0
  \end{bmatrix} &&
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -150\\ 239\\ -90\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1
  \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
form a basis for the null space of $A$. Do you see how these correspond to a
basis for the null space of $T$?

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped. I wanted to go the matrix approach at first but because there is a follow up similar question where the domain is polynomial degree at most 999, and co-domain is $\mathbb{R^{100}}$. Just that there, they require only the dimension not the basis. Thus I thought there was a more abstract approach.